glb exported by blender doesn't show texture in react-three-fiber
I have created a .blender file and export it as glb. But when I either load it in glb online viewer or via react-three-fiber, none of them show the texture.
The blender and exported glb file is in the public assets of the code. Can anyone help?

Can you describe what export settings you are using?
As i used to have similar problems and I solved them by messing around with the export settings until i found the right way
